# Converting a light switch to a Boolean toggle switch

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have a system in which there is a screw with an electrical contact on it. When the screw is in all the way, one electrical connection is made. When it is out all the way, another connection is made. If it is in-between, no connection exists and my circuit doesn't work. I can adjust the endpoints which determine what is "in" and what is "out". The piece is from a garage opener that I am trying to repurpose. Here is a picture of the system.

[image]

I *can* control my unit with this setup, however I would like to use a light switch, since turning a dial really isn't as easy as flipping a switch. The lightswitch, unfortunately toggles between on and off. I would like to control between connections 1 and 2 instead, since another switch gives power to the unit. Is there a way I can do this or am I just going about this entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

The light switch is a single-throw switch; you need a double-throw switch for what you're doing. Most electronics suppliers should have one for the voltage and current you need.

Comment: Well, I just now popped open the switch casing and soldered a spring to the (-) and wired that to the exposed grounding screw... It's seeming to work, but I'm wondering if there was an easier way. In any case it's possible with the switch I have. :)

Comment: Good to know...